# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Bad file descriptor with Laravel and MacOS M1 Pro

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, macos, mamp

I bought the new mac bookpro with M1 processor (ARM architecture) but I have difficulty in making all the projects work that on the old mac (intel architecture) worked without problems.
On the new MACBOOK, any project that requires a database connection, gives me this error:

```
SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Bad file descriptor
```

As if it could not find the driver to make the connection, but the driver is present. Also I have installed:

**MAMP PRO for M1
Brew
Composer (via brew)
Subversion (via brew)
Rosette 2
MySql**

I tried to repeat the installation several times both in "ARM" and "x86" format but the error persists. Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was LULU, it was blocking the MAMP exit process. [RESOLVED]